# Unable to create sub site in sharepoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, sub-site

I try to creating a sub site but always getting error

> Sorry, you don't have access to this page.

My account has full control rights on this site, I further investigate and found that i had no rights on top level site (I mean site collection root site). Let me know any body knows this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue yesterday and the below solution worked for me.

Gave read access for **SharePoint Taxonomy Hidden List** for all authenticated users (or only the owners if you wish) operating within the site collection.
This list is hidden and does not inherit permissions.

you can find it by browsing directly to `/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList`.

Posting the solution so that it helps others.

Ref : http://www.brightworksupport.com/user-with-full-control-cannot-create-sub-sites-or-projects/

Comment: Thanks Ahuja ..
Mark this as the answer @nagendra!

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU... this bug is a real stinker! but the fix is easy once you know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have permission level of creating subsites on the top level site too to be able to create a site in your sub-site.

> However, the SharePoint sites are managed by the sites’ hierarchy and every top level site can have several subsites. It is necessary for us to have the corresponding permission on the top level site if we want to create a subsite in the subsite of the top level site.

Here is a similar situation that you are facing, refer [this](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/200687.aspx)

Comment: Hi Vipul, I given myself Full control rights on top level site but still facing the issue and verified permission levels create sub sites and manage permissions are enabled.

Comment: Are you able to now create a sub-site under the root site collection ?

Comment: **No**, I am unable to create sub site in root site collection.

Comment: Are you using a custom template/custom master page. Do you get this issue only for a specific set of templates or all OOB templates ? Also, did you add yourself explicitly as full control user ? Are the users in site owners group at root site collection able to create subsites ?

Comment: I am trying to create default team site only, few things I let you know that this is **migrated** site collection from 2010 and I issue **on only this site collection** the same ( permissions & permission level) am able to create sub sites in other site collection.